# Broken Aurelia binding when object is null

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

Example based on [Aurelia doc](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-selects/3).

Page code:

```
export class MyPage {
    products = [
        { id: 0, name: 'Motherboard' },
        { id: 1, name: 'CPU' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Memory' },
    ];

    selectedProduct = null;    
}
```

Page HTML:

```
<label>
    Select product:<br/>
    <select value.bind="selectedProduct">
        <option model.bind="null">Choose...</option>
        <option repeat.for="product of products"
                model.bind="product">
            ${product.id} - ${product.name}
        </option>
    </select>
</label>

<div if.bind="selectedProduct">
    Selected product 1: ${selectedProduct.id} - ${selectedProduct.name}

    <div if.bind="selectedProduct.id > 0">
        Selected product 2: ${selectedProduct.id} - ${selectedProduct.name}
    </div>
</div>
```

When selecting CPU, then selecting null value, then selecting Memory, *Selected product 1* is updated correctly with a value from a select element, but *Selected product 2* is stuck with a *CPU* value.

**How to bind selected value correctly inside the inner div?**

In my application, I want to be able to display a content of selected item. Depending on an item type, I have a several `<div if.bind="item.type === N">...</div>` elements in order to display different HTML for each type of an item.

Note: binding doesn't work with newest packages, but works fine when I assign specific versions to the following packages in my package.json:

- "aurelia-templating": "1.4.2"
- "aurelia-templating-binding": "1.3.0"
- "aurelia-templating-resources": "1.4.0"
- "aurelia-templating-router": "1.1.0"

Comment: Let's start with, why `null`...`null` equal to unknown...when you evaluate this `${message.title}` in your component template, what do you expects to happen...it breaks of course, because `message` is not an object now, it's an unknown representation(null)

Comment: As I have a if.bind="message" on myComponent, I expect myComponent to disappear. I want to have a messages list and want to display message when clicked / hide message when navigating back to messages list.

Comment: Just tried if.bind on my component: `<my-component if.bind="messageShown" message.bind="messageShown"></my-component>` - now a title is broken too.

Comment: Maybe related http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-selects/3

Comment: For the second `if.bind`, perhaps try checking if `message.type` exists first?  e.g., `if.bind="message.type && message.type === 1)"`

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. Even tried `if.bind="message && message.type && message.type === 1"` - still title works fine, content doesn't work.

Comment: @Hackerman - thanks to your link I was able to simplify an example. The issue occurs even when not using a custom component.